# Share a filtered PowerBI report without the ability to remove filter

Tags: web, powerbi, dax

In Power BI we can share filtered views to users by editing the URL. Once user clicks on URL from an application then they will navigate to Power BI Report. 
Through URL only we have filtered records. Like -

http://XXXXXXXX/reports/powerbi/XXXXXXX/<"Report_Name">?filter=<"Data_Set">/<"Column"> eq 'Value'&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false

When Users edit the above url and removes the condition from the Url , Like - http://XXXXXXXX/reports/powerbi/XXXXXXX/<"Report_Name">. Then, they can see all data from the report. Which is not permissible for them.

Is there any ways, Either we could restrict edit or Mask the URL. So, they can not edit ?

Thanking You.

Comment: I do not believe this is possible when you publish via URL, this concept is that in principle the URL is accecable by everyone. I propose you use embedded powerbi with row level security.

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is can be achieved by Row-level security. You can find how to do it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wN33rTaiB4

**Row-Level Security**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls

But if you don't want to do this, you can also use Share Report views. Please find the link below on how to do it. But this will still let them change the filter.
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-service-and-mobile-june-2018-feature-summary/#sharing-reports-filters-and-slicers